# Website With json sorting different array's with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying things out in javascript with my website where it is possible to stream multiple series with just one html file thanks to search querys and a json file with the information. but now i want to make a home site with the series sorted by the air date of the latest ep. But I've put everything in different array's named after the serie so i could easely access the serie's data with the search query. but i don't seem to find any way to sort those different array's with each other.

my json:

```
{
 "arifureta": [
        {
            "name": "arifureta",
            "trailer": "https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-9rlskzipxxaw.html",
            "latest_ep": 4,
            "episodes": {
                "1": {
                    "address": "https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-rnah6dqcym96.html",
                    "date": "8-7-2019"
                },
                "2": {
                    "address": " https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-y93t9mysnnun.html",
                    "date": "15-7-2019"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "boku_no_hero_academia": [
        {
            "name": "Boku no hero academia",
            "trailer": "trailer.mp4",
            "latest_ep": 4
            "episodes": {
                "1": {
                    "address": "ep1.mp4",
                    "date": "3-4-2019"
                },
                "2": {
                    "address": "ep2.mp4",
                    "date": "10-4-2019"
                }
            }
        }
    ]` 
}
```

I don't really have a usable javascript besides the basic .sort( (a, b) => {}), and i've tried a bunch of things but i can't seem to sort it.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[CodeSandbox DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-tereshkova-fzbr5)**

Since the data is an object then we need to use `Object.entries`, because objects can't be sorted. `Object.entries` return an array of key-value pairs, which can be simply sorted/filtered as you need.

```js
function getEpisodes(entry) {
  return Object.values(entry[1][0].episodes);
}

function getCloserEpisodeDate(episodes) {
  return parseDate(
    episodes.sort((a, b) => parseDate(a.date) < parseDate(b.date))[0].date
  );
}

function getSortedEntries(data) {
  const entries = Object.entries(data);
  return entries.sort(
    (a, b) =>
      getCloserEpisodeDate(getEpisodes(a)) <
      getCloserEpisodeDate(getEpisodes(b))
  );
}
```

Dates in `episodes` are not valid for `Date()` constructor, that's why we need to parse it and build a new Date object from it. `Date` is useful for comparison.

```js
function parseDate(date) {
  var [day, month, year] = date.split("-");
  return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
}
```